# Couple of differential equations to solve.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to sanity check that I'm doing the right process here. High level question first... why can we just treat derivative notation as a fraction and separate the differentials?

1. $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x\sin{x}}{y}, y(0) = -1
   $$

   $$ y\;dy = x  \sin{x}\; dx $$

   now we integrate:

   $$ \frac{y^2}{2} + c = -x  \cos{x} + \sin{x} + C $$

   $$ y^2 = 2(-x  \cos{x} + \sin{x} + C) $$

   $$ y = \sqrt{2(-x  \cos{x} + \sin{x} + C)} $$

   To satisfy the initial condition $y(0) = -1$, I plug in $x=0$

   $$ y = \sqrt{2C} $$

   $$ -1 = \sqrt{2C} $$

This is weird right? What did I do wrong?

2. $$\frac{dy}{dx} = xe^y,\quad  \frac{dy}{e^y} = xdx$$

Again, why can we do this? We're treating the derivative as a fraction?

$$-e^{-y} = \frac{x^2}{2} + C,\quad e^{-y} = \frac{-x^2}{2} - C$$

take the ln of both sides:

$$-y = \ln(\frac{-x^2}{2} - C),\quad y = -\ln(\frac{-x^2}{2} - C)$$

$$y = \ln\biggr(\frac{1}{\frac{-x^2}{2} - C}\biggr),\quad 
y = \ln\biggr(\frac{2}{-x^2 - 2C}\biggr)$$

so if $y(0) = 0$, then $-2c = 2$ so $c = -1$

so the solution:

$$y = \ln\biggr(\frac{2}{-x^2 + 2}\biggr)$$

Is that right?

Comment: $y^2 = f(x) \implies y = \pm \sqrt {f(x)} \implies -1 = -\sqrt {f(0)}$

Comment: Ah makes sense. @DougM wanna give a full answer and I'll give you credit? everything else look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

$y = -\sqrt {2\sin x - 2x\cos x + 1}\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = -\frac {2\cos x - 2\cos x + 2\sin x}{2\sqrt{2\sin x - 2x\cos x + 1}} = \frac {\sin x}{y}$

And $y(0)  = -1$

2)

$y = \ln \left(\frac {2}{2-x^2}\right)\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{2-x^2}{2} \frac {4x}{(2-x^2)^2}=\frac {2x}{2-x^2}= xe^y$

and $y(0) = 0$

Looks good.